# Delete a node from XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have to delete a node from the XML file based on the value coming in the child element of those nodes.
Actual file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<_-AMS_-OBRXINVOIC02>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
  <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
     <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
     <MANDT>132</MANDT>
     <DOCNUM>001</DOCNUM>
     <DOCREL>620</DOCREL>
     <STATUS>30</STATUS>
     <DIRECT>1</DIRECT>
     <OUTMOD>4</OUTMOD>
     <IDOCTYP>INVOIC02</IDOCTYP>
     <CIMTYP>/AMS/OBRXINVOIC02</CIMTYP>
     <MESTYP>INVOIC</MESTYP>
     <SNDPOR>SAPABI</SNDPOR>
     <SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
     <SNDPRN>ABIPRR3132</SNDPRN>
     <RCVPOR>XIS</RCVPOR>
     <RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT>
     <RCVPFC>LS</RCVPFC>
     <RCVPRN>BREEDI0001</RCVPRN>
     <CREDAT>20110406</CREDAT>
     <CRETIM>071233</CRETIM>
     <SERIAL>20110406071232</SERIAL>
  </EDI_DC40>
  <E1EDK01 SEGMENT="1">
     <CURCY>BRL</CURCY>
     <HWAER>BRL</HWAER>
     <WKURS>1.00000</WKURS>
     <ZTERM>Z171</ZTERM>
     <BSART>INVO</BSART>
     <BELNR>0969286361</BELNR>
     <NTGEW>2949.090</NTGEW>
     <BRGEW>3329.780</BRGEW>
     <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
     <FKART_RL>ZLR</FKART_RL>
     <RECIPNT_NO>0001061877</RECIPNT_NO>
     <FKTYP>L</FKTYP>
     <_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDK01 SEGMENT="1">
        <ANZPK>00449</ANZPK>
        <VOLTOT>7.688</VOLTOT>
        <SERIES>001</SERIES>
        <NFNUM>000000</NFNUM>
        <NFTYPE>V1</NFTYPE>
        <MODEL>55</MODEL>
        <PSTDAT>20110406</PSTDAT>
        <CREDAT>20110406</CREDAT>
        <CRETIM>034335</CRETIM>
        <NFFRE>0.00</NFFRE>
        <NFINS>0.00</NFINS>
        <NFOTH>0.00</NFOTH>
        <NFDIS>2200.90-</NFDIS>
        <NFNET>28757.95</NFNET>
        <NFTOT>28186.49</NFTOT>
        <ZNFNET>28186.49</ZNFNET>
        <PROCESS>X</PROCESS>
        <NFENUM>000423391</NFENUM>
     </_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDK01>
  </E1EDK01>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>RS</PARVW>
     <LIFNR>0001061877</LIFNR>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <BNAME>BRSANTOSRO5</BNAME>
     <PAORG>BRN1</PAORG>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>1B</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0000899500</PARTN>
     <NAME1>L6 BRN1 KA CAR FL Matriz Dia</NAME1>
     <ORT01>Sao Paulo</ORT01>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <REGIO>SP</REGIO>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>1C</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0000899499</PARTN>
     <NAME1>L5 BRN1 KA Car FL Matriz Dia</NAME1>
     <ORT01>Sao Paulo</ORT01>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <REGIO>SP</REGIO>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>1D</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0002766603</PARTN>
     <NAME1>L4 BRN1 KA Car Dia</NAME1>
     <ORT01>Rio de Janeiro</ORT01>
     <PSTLZ>22775-112</PSTLZ>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <REGIO>RJ</REGIO>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>SS</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0000899472</PARTN>
     <NAME1>L3 BRN1 KA Carrefour</NAME1>
     <ORT01>Sao Paulo</ORT01>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <REGIO>SP</REGIO>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>SS</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0000021177</PARTN>
     <NAME1>AMS View</NAME1>
     <ORT01>Vevey</ORT01>
     <LAND1>CH</LAND1>
     <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
     <ANRED>Sociedade</ANRED>
     <REGIO>VD</REGIO>
     <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>1G</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0000021174</PARTN>
     <NAME1>Global View</NAME1>
     <ORT01>Vevey</ORT01>
     <LAND1>CH</LAND1>
     <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
     <ANRED>Sociedade</ANRED>
     <REGIO>VD</REGIO>
     <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0001061877</PARTN>
     <NAME1>Dia Brasil Sociedade Ltda</NAME1>
     <STRAS>R Agricola La Paz Tristante SN</STRAS>
     <ORT01>Osasco</ORT01>
     <PSTLZ>06276-035</PSTLZ>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <TELF1>11 38868131</TELF1>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <ORT02>Pq Industrial Anhanguera</ORT02>
     <REGIO>SP</REGIO>
     <ILNNR>7899288907049</ILNNR>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>SS</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0001061877</PARTN>
     <NAME1>Dia Brasil Sociedade Ltda</NAME1>
     <STRAS>R Agricola La Paz Tristante SN</STRAS>
     <ORT01>Osasco</ORT01>
     <PSTLZ>06276-035</PSTLZ>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <TELF1>11 38868131</TELF1>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <ORT02>Pq Industrial Anhanguera</ORT02>
     <REGIO>SP</REGIO>
     <ILNNR>7899288907049</ILNNR>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
     <_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
        <STCD1>03476811021159</STCD1>
        <STCD3>492.488.462.119</STCD3>
     </_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>RG</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0000658366</PARTN>
     <NAME1>Carrefour Com e Industria Ltda</NAME1>
     <STRAS>Av das Americas 5150</STRAS>
     <ORT01>Rio de Janeiro</ORT01>
     <PSTLZ>22640-102</PSTLZ>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <TELF1>21 4313011</TELF1>
     <TELFX>21 3252624</TELFX>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <ORT02>Barra da Tijuca</ORT02>
     <REGIO>RJ</REGIO>
     <ILNNR>7891103001024</ILNNR>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
     <_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
        <STCD1>45543915000262</STCD1>
        <STCD3>81536600</STCD3>
     </_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>TF</PARVW>
     <PARTN>0100301696</PARTN>
     <NAME1>Transportadora Nosei Ltda</NAME1>
     <STRAS>Rua Carlos Weber 512</STRAS>
     <ORT01>Sao Paulo</ORT01>
     <PSTLZ>05303-000</PSTLZ>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <TELF1>11 38329460</TELF1>
     <TELFX>11 38329460</TELFX>
     <SPRAS>P</SPRAS>
     <ORT02>Vila Leopoldina</ORT02>
     <REGIO>SP</REGIO>
     <SPRAS_ISO>PT</SPRAS_ISO>
     <_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
        <STCD1>54043435000142</STCD1>
        <STCD3>111173871116</STCD3>
     </_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
     <PARVW>BK</PARVW>
     <LIFNR>BR10</LIFNR>
     <NAME1>Nestle Brasil Ltda</NAME1>
     <STRAS>Av Dr Chucri Zaidan 246</STRAS>
     <ORT01>Sao Paulo</ORT01>
     <COUNC>SP</COUNC>
     <PSTLZ>04583-110</PSTLZ>
     <LAND1>BR</LAND1>
     <TELF1>11 55084400</TELF1>
     <TELFX>11 55085475</TELFX>
     <ORT02>Vila Cordeiro</ORT02>
     <REGIO>SP</REGIO>
     <_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
        <ZCCODE>7891000001004</ZCCODE>
     </_-AMS_-OBR_E1EDKA1>
  </E1EDKA1>
  <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
     <QUALF>001</QUALF>
     <BELNR>813763</BELNR>
     <DATUM>20110404</DATUM>
  </E1EDK02>
  <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
     <IDDAT>024</IDDAT>
     <DATUM>20110406</DATUM>
  </E1EDK03>
  <E1EDK17 SEGMENT="1">
     <QUALF>002</QUALF>
     <LKOND>CIF</LKOND>
     <LKTEXT>Custo, Seguro e Frete</LKTEXT>
  </E1EDK17>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>3565689</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>BANCO ABN AMRO REAL S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>S#o Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>5704752</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>00191893</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>Banco Do Brasil S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>331415</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>00193070</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>BANCO DO BRASIL S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>São Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>331415</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>47901</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>BANKBOSTON BANCO MULTIPLO SA</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>89821</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>23722372</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>BANCO BRADESCO S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>São Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>4617</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>1040988</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>Caixa Economica Federal</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>30001500</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>74551</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>Banco Citibank S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>1002058</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>3999454</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>HSBC Bank Brasil S A-Banco Multiplo</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>4425</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>3417912</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>Banco Itau S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>1445</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>34172938</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>Banco Itau S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>82</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>1511935</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>Banco Nossa Caixa S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>4100342</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>03372271</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>BANCO DO ESTADO DE SAO PAULO SA BANESPA</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>13001181-7</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDK28 SEGMENT="1">
     <BCOUN>BR</BCOUN>
     <BRNUM>4090352</BRNUM>
     <BNAME>Unibanco Uniao De Bancos Brasileiros S A</BNAME>
     <BALOC>Sao Paulo</BALOC>
     <ACNUM>102049</ACNUM>
  </E1EDK28>
  <E1EDKT1 SEGMENT="1">
     <TDID>Z018</TDID>
     <TSSPRAS>P</TSSPRAS>
     <TSSPRAS_ISO>PT</TSSPRAS_ISO>
     <E1EDKT2 SEGMENT="1">
        <TDLINE>&quot;O dest.deverá,nas operações com merc ou prest de serv receb c imposto</TDLINE>
        <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
     </E1EDKT2>
     <E1EDKT2 SEGMENT="1">
        <TDLINE>retido,escrit o doc fiscal nos termos art 278 do RICMS&quot;.</TDLINE>
     </E1EDKT2>
  </E1EDKT1>
  <E1EDKT1 SEGMENT="1">
     <TDID>Z019</TDID>
     <TSSPRAS>P</TSSPRAS>
     <TSSPRAS_ISO>PT</TSSPRAS_ISO>
     <E1EDKT2 SEGMENT="1">
        <TDLINE>VENDAS COM CONDIÇÃO CIF</TDLINE>
        <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
     </E1EDKT2>
  </E1EDKT1>
  <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
     <QUALF>008</QUALF>
     <ORGID>BRN1</ORGID>
  </E1EDK14>
  <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
     <QUALF>007</QUALF>
     <ORGID>06</ORGID>
  </E1EDK14>
  <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
     <QUALF>006</QUALF>
     <ORGID>00</ORGID>
  </E1EDK14>
  <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
     <QUALF>015</QUALF>
     <ORGID>F2</ORGID>
  </E1EDK14>
  <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
     <QUALF>003</QUALF>
     <ORGID>BR10</ORGID>
  </E1EDK14>
  <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
     <SUMID>011</SUMID>
     <SUMME>28186.49</SUMME>
     <WAERQ>BRL</WAERQ>
  </E1EDS01>
  <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
     <SUMID>010</SUMID>
     <SUMME>24332.15</SUMME>
     <WAERQ>BRL</WAERQ>
  </E1EDS01>
```

My requirment is that I want to remove the entire segment "E1EDKA1" from the file if its child element "PARVW" is coming with value "SS".
In my case I want to remove the 3 segments of "E1EDKA1" whose PARVW is coming as SS

I tried from my side: My code is below:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(fis);
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("E1EDKA1");
        System.out.println(nList.getLength());
        if (nList != null && nList.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength();i++) {
Node node = nList.item(i);
            //    System.out.println(node);
                Element e = (Element) node;

                NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("PARVW");
                String title = nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                System.out.println(title);
                    if (title.equals("SS")) {
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    doc.getFirstChild().removeChild(node);
             }
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/ssourav/Desktop/Idoc12_out123.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Please help me to get this output and suggest me where is the problem in the code.
actually the program gets out as it encounters the first "SS" value and nothing has been written to the output file.

Comment: You want to do this in java or javascript ?

Comment: Hi 
I want to do it in Java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing is written I think you get an exception. Are you catching it with no trace?

Try removing the node this way: `e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);`

Answer (score 1):

```
    XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*/E1EDKA1[PARVW/text()='SS']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        nl.item(i).getParentNode().removeChild(nl.item(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
 void removeElement(Document docObj) {
        NodeList records= doc.getElementsByTagName("EDI_DC40");
        Element record= null;

        //iterate over all records
        for(int i=0; i<records.getLength();i++){
            record= (Element) records.item(i);
            Node statusNode = emp.getElementsByTagName("STATUS").item(0);
            record.removeChild(statusNode);
        }

    }
```