# Remove a node using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, domdocument

I have an xml structure as follows:

```
<a>
   <b>
      <foo>null</foo>
   </b>
   <b>
      <foo>abc</foo>
   </b>
   <b>
      <foo>efg</foo>
   </b>
</a>
```

I am using `org.w3c.dom.Document` to update the nodes. when `<foo>` has a value `null`, I want to remove

```
<b>
  <foo>null</foo>
</b>
```

Is this possible? I know I can call `removeChild(childElement)`, but not sure how I can specify to remove the specific nested element above.

**Update:** With the answer below, I tried:

```
String query = "/a/b[foo[text() = 'null']]";
Object result = (xpath.compile(newQuery)).evaluate(doc, NODE);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
{
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    doc.removeChild(node);
}
```

I get `NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete a node from XML file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925255/delete-a-node-from-xml-file-in-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
doc.removeChild(node);
```

will not work because the node you're trying to remove isn't a child of the document node, it's a child of the *document element* (the `a`), which itself is a child of the document root node. You need to call `removeChild` on the correct parent node:

```
node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
```

Comment: VBA equivalent is node.ParentNode.RemoveChild node

Answer (score 3):

To get that node you can use XPath:

```
/a/b[foo[text() = 'null']]
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But if I call removeChild on that, will it remove just the `<foo>null</foo>`, or `<b><foo>null</foo></b>`. Also I don't want to touch the root node `<a>`.

Comment: According to tour question you want to remove `<b>
  <foo>null</foo>
</b>`, right?

Comment: yes. I was thinking this query will also try to remove/modify `<a>`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am trying with the new query, but I am still getting an error. Any suggestions?